# Saving a file on the client side of my React application

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs

I am trying to save a file on the client side of my react application. 
The data is obtained from my API Controller called DownloadDocument.
I am returning FileSreamResult from my DownloadDocument method.
FileStreamResult reads the data and writes it to the response in the react API. 
The network tab gets a response, but when i log the response i get a response of null.
I am using file-saver to try and save the file. https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver.

Does anyone have any recommendations on what the issue is or if there is a better way of doing?

My action in the controller:

The issue that i am having is that my response for the react api is coming back null.

```
[HttpGet("{documentId}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS", "GET")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadDocument(int documentId)
    {
      if (documentId != 0)
      {
        var document = await service.DownloadDocumentAsync(documentId);

        var documentResponse = File(document, "application/octet-stream");             
        return documentResponse;
      }
      return BadRequest("Document id is not valid");
    }
```

react application.

```
api.indexes.downloadDocument(clones)
    .then(response=>{
    console.log(response)
    let FileSaver = require('file-saver');
    let blob = new Blob([response], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    let filename ="testdownload"
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add this to the header.
responseType: 'blob'

this article explains it well
https://medium.com/@fakiolinho/handle-blobs-requests-with-axios-the-right-way-bb905bdb1c04